# Computed Column - as Primary key

Tags: t-sql, primary-key, sql-server-2014, calculated-columns, create-table

I have the following Computed Column within the create table function:

```
Create table test
(
Code1 nchar(10),
Code2 nchar (10),
Type nchar(10),
Final AS CASE WHEN LEN(Code1)>0 THEN Code1 WHEN LEN(Code2)>0 THEN Code2 ELSE Type END
);

Alter table test
add constraint PK_Test1
Primary Key (Final)
```

But I am getting the following error

> "Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table".

This is because Code 1, Code 2 and Type can be NULL, but all the three will never be NULL. One of them will always have a value.

Is there anyway I can get define the computed column as a primary key with the above in mind?

Many thanks - JT

Comment: How would the semantics of the value " " (ie single space) ever be different from that desired of NULL for each of these fields? If not, then simply make them all NOT NULL and use single space in place of a NULL value. This will also simplify your lookup and join logic for this table everywhere.

Comment: If either answer solved your problem, you may want to mark the question as answered (there should be a checkmark to the left of the answers). If neither of them did, please edit your question to add more detail so that it can be (correctly) answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your computed column needs to be persisted and NOT NULL to be used as a primary key;

```
Create table test
(
    Code1 nchar(10),
    Code2 nchar (10),
    Type nchar(10),
    Final AS CASE WHEN LEN(Code1)>0 THEN Code1 
                  WHEN LEN(Code2)>0 THEN Code2 
                  ELSE Type END 
          PERSISTED NOT NULL
);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/653c6/1).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a [unique constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187550.aspx) as it will allow null

> Unlike PRIMARY KEY constraints, UNIQUE constraints allow for the value
>   NULL. However, as with any value participating in a UNIQUE constraint,
>   only one null value is allowed per column. A UNIQUE constraint can be
>   referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.